# Set up rails to find the default location of LIBMYSQL.dll

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, windows

I am on windows 7 and set up mysql through XAMPP.

I am now starting a new rails project (my first time developing in rails), and just set up the project.

I wanted to start the server so I used `rails server`. However it is complaining that

> "The program can't start because LIBMYSQL.dll is missing from your computer"

I know where libmysql.dll is stored at, so how do I tell rails to look there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Libmysql.dll** file is located in the bin directory of your mysql installation.

There also needs to be a copy of it in the **Ruby\bin** directory.

Copy it there and restart your server or console, if you are already run it.

Comment: A more detailed discussion and solution for this problem is available on [installing-mysql-on-windows-7-x64-and-using-ruby-with-it](http://blog.mmediasys.com/2011/07/07/installing-mysql-on-windows-7-x64-and-using-ruby-with-it/)

Comment: The location of this file has moved in the latest version of MySQL - it is now in the lib folder. My default installation location is C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQLServer 5.5\lib\libmysql.dll

Comment: If you have 32-bit Ruby but 64-bit MySQL, you need the 32-bit version of this DLL (it'll still work against your 64-bit server).  You can get it from the C connector.  See more here: http://blog.mmediasys.com/2011/07/07/installing-mysql-on-windows-7-x64-and-using-ruby-with-it/

Comment: Any solution that involves copying a DLL to a specific location other than where it was installed or intended by the library maintainer is not a good solution.